# Why is Madame Roland considered a heroine during French Revolution?

Tags: political-history, french-revolution, women

I'm working on an assignment about [Madame Roland](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Madame_Roland) and [Olympe De Gouges](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Olympe_de_Gouges), and a question says:

> What is their common position on the political regime in France? Which ones do they support? Which party do they belong to?

I know that Olympe De Gouges wants equality between women and men, however in the documents related to the homework there is this about Mme Roland:

> She wanted to put her knowledge and ideas at the service of the Republic, without claiming a leading political role for women. ... Destined to put women "in their place"

So I guess she didn't want equality between men and women. I read in different articles that she is considered a heroine during the Revolution, I guess she contributed to other things.

---

Back to the question, I know that Madame Roland and Olympes De Gouges belong to the [Girondins](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Girondins) party, but I can't find what they have in common and which one they support. (The first two question marks of the question).

If you think I shouldn't seek an answer here, just link some documents if possible.

Hope you can help me.

[link to document related to assignment](https://www.histoire-image.org/fr/etudes/madame-roland-engagement-politique-femmes-revolution) (In french so you might want to translate if you are interested)

Comment: Asking an answer here is fine, though the usual process would be for you to read their wiki entries first... Which, incidentally, may very well answer your question.

Comment: I did and I can't find wether she is for equality or not

Comment: They were both Girondins, and differed on how women fit in society.

Comment: So Madame Roland didn't really want total equality between men and women, she wanted woment to be "at their place", unlike Olympe De Gouges

Comment: Yeah, but that's just the background stuff and needs to be put in the context of the times. (You know, men not getting universal suffrage until 1848 and women not getting suffrage until WW2.) The crux of the matter is that they were both supportive of the Girondins. (Ne cherche pas minuit à quatre heures, à moins qu'il y ait quelque chose de plus dans ton doc inaccessible.)

Comment: okay, can you correct me on the following: they are both Girondins so they support Ancien Regime or La Monarchie. thank you for your help

Comment: I'll file that question under: you need to read up a bit on the Girondins.

Comment: Okay, thank you for your help

Comment: Aside: [*excellent* podcast](https://www.revolutionspodcast.com/2014/07/31-the-three-estates-.html) (50+ episodes) on the topic if you feel like digging deep into the topic.